# Excel circular reference with six simple formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I thought I was reasonably sharp when it comes to avoiding circular references in excel but this time am truly stuck. I have lost alot of hair over this ...

This is a simple government subsidy exercise. Users pay the government for gas. First tier of consumption is free. Second tier is subsidized. Government provides a lump contribution ($4,263m). Anything left after `Revenue + Subsidy - Expenditure` (for all tiers) is used to subsidize tariff of second tier.

Remaining contribution is divided by volume of demand for Tier two, and then subtracted from the tier two tariff ($15/tonne) Tier three revenue is fixed to make things simple.

I have structured the model per the image below. You can see all the formulas I have used. All rows that are not yellow are hard coded, therefore no formulas in these. I have enabled iterative calculations ... but excel just keeps on spitting wrong answers. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong and how to solve this issue? :) Is there for example a way I can rewrite the 'subsidy available from contribution' formula to avoid the circularity?

[image]

Comment: Here is your circle, where each arrow means "referes to": K14 -> K9 -> K25 -> K23 -> K21 -> K16 -> K14

Comment: Jordan, thank you for your answer. I have stepped through your circle and that is absolutely correct. Are you saying it is the formula in K14 that should be re-written?

Comment: Should cell K14 be referencing cell K9 and not K8?

Comment: Hello Jordan -no. Revenue for tier two should be using the 'subsidized' tariff, which is the normal tariff minus anything left over from the government subsidy. That is where the circularity is coming from, I think

Comment: Well at the moment you're working out the subsidy by referring to it in the same formula, you'll need to calculate the subsidy first, then calculate the tier two revenue. The only way this seems viable to me is by using the tier two tariff and tier two volume.

Comment: I can't do that Jordan. The only tariff for tier two is the 'tier two with rebate' tariff. Remember this tariff also defines the total revenue for tier two. I can't work out the subsidy in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you should be calculating the "Tier 2 subsidized tariff" as an output - it shouldn't be an input in your calculation. Instead of the total 'funding from operations' in this calculaton you need to have a 'Tier 1 and 3 funding.' The amount of money still needed to cover operating costs will be the total revenue from Tier 2, and divide this by the Tier 2 volumne to get your $/tonne.

Formulas:
[Screenshot with formulas shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr2Me.png)

Results:
[Screenshot with calculated values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2GE2.png)

If there is a chance that you'll have more revenue from Tier 3 than needed to cover all costs, you might add an 'if' statement to this to make sure your tier 2 cost doesn't go below 0.

Comment: Neal -that is indeed the answer. And it is beautifully simple. Cannot believe I got blown off course so badly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use formula to determine "tariff rebate". circular reference is telling you that you are dealing with x=x situation here. so if you replace numbers with variable names you end up with calculating "Subsidy Available from Contribution" without need of tariff rebate. Here is what I came up with:

[image: solution]